# If the restrictions of an element of $\operatorname{Spec}R$ to a cover of $\operatorname{Spec}R$ is zero, then the element is zero

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, ideals, maximal-and-prime-ideals, localization

Let $R$ be a ring, $X=\operatorname{Spec}R$, and write $X_f$ for $X\setminus V(f)$.

We know that $X_g\subset X_f$ iff $g\in \sqrt{(f)}$ iff $g^n=fh$ for some $n \in  \mathbb{N}$ and $h\in R$. So there is a well-defined map $R_f\rightarrow R_g$ given by $\frac{a}{f^m}\mapsto\frac{ah^m}{g^{nm}}$ whenever $X_g\subset X_f$. Here $R_f$ stands for the localization of $R$ w.r.t. $\{f,f^2,\dots\}$.

Now I have a few questions about the proof of the following lemma from Mumford's "Red Book":

[image: Lemma]

First, I don't understand how the equivalence of statement 4 with the other ones follows. (The first three statements are indeed clearly equivalent.)

Second, why $g$ goes to $0$ in $R_P$? Since Mumford appeals to the commutativity of the diagram, I need to trace where $g$ goes under the upper arrow and further under the right arrow. Since $X_{f_\alpha}\subset X_f$, it follows that $f^k_{\alpha}=fh$ for some $k\in \mathbb{N}$ and $h\in R$, and so under the upper arrow I have $\frac{b}{f^n}\mapsto\frac{bh^n}{f_{\alpha}^{nk}}$. To understand what is its image under the right arrow, I asked [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1986031/what-are-r-p-and-a-natural-map-r-f-rightarrow-r-p-in-mumfords-red-book/) (general) question, but I'm still not sure about this map. The image must be zero. Why is this so?

Thirdly, I'm not sure about the last sentence. Of course we arrive at a contradiction to the fact that $A\subset P$. However we started with assuming that $g\ne 0$, and to finish the proof we must show that there exists an index $\alpha_0$ such that the image of $g$ in $R_{f_{\alpha_0}}$ is nonzero. I guess this $\alpha_0$ equals $\alpha$, but I can't see why the image of $g$ in $R_{f_\alpha}$ equals zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First $\sqrt{A}=\bigcap\limits_{A\subseteq P, P\text{prime}} P$; this is a basic result in  algebra (using AC).

Second, $g$ goes to zero by the commutative diagram, as it goes to zero in $R_{f_{\alpha}}$.

Third, the idea is $g\neq 0\Rightarrow \neg iv\Rightarrow \text{contradiction}$

Comment: So Mumford assumes the hypothesis (and for this reason $g$ goes to zero in $R_{f_\alpha}$, right?) and also that $g\ne 0$ and gets $g=0$, a contradiction. I thought he assumes only that $g\ne 0$ and proves that there is some element in the cover in which $g$ has nonzero image. One more question: where did he use that $[P]\in X_{f_\alpha}$?

Comment: Yeah he has two assumptions $g\neq 0$ and $g$ goes to zero locally, then he gets a contradiction.